# MySQL - Troubles connecting from anything other than localhost

Tags: debian, mysql

## Background

So I have a web server on a raspberry pi which works perfectly fine. The web server uses MySQL in the background and web pages can do queries without an issue. Recently I want to make direct connections to the MySQL server instead without going through the web server. I have installed `phpmyadmin` to my server machine (RaspberryPi) and can connect using `host.com/phpmyadmin` per the help of tutorials online. This all works great and I have no issue at this point. However, whenever I try to connect from either across the internet, or even on the same network, it does not work.

## What I have tried

So from the RaspberryPi itself, I have installed `mysql-client`, and I am able to successfully connect to itself and perform a query. This shows that my parameters of connecting work at this point.

The next step, I try to connect from a computer within the same network. I have chosen to use HeidiSQL as my client. I have `hostname = 192.168.0.106` (the server's local IP), port `3306` or `80`, `user = valid` user as well as password. At this point it can't connect to the server. I have verified that the port being used is 3306, standard from installation.

Am I missing something from the MySQL side to allow others to connect to it? Perhaps something very simple I am missing.

Comment: Please provide the relevant information from your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: maybe you need edit hosts.deny / hosts.allow and if you using iptables you need to edit your firewall settings too. You can check out on what interface and ports mysql is listening to with netstat -tulpn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make MySQL listen on all interfaces

Your version of MySQL may be listening on the localhost interface (127.0.0.1 etc) by default*. You can make it listen on a specific interface, or all interfaces if you prefer.

To let it listen on all interfaces:

- open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- comment out the the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` ( → `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`)
- restart MySQL (eg `sudo service mysql restart` or however you are managing services)

* Note that per the documentation, the default address is `0.0.0.0`, but distributions may change this.

Reference: [Server Command Options (`--bind-address`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address)

Comment: This seems to fix the first problem so thank you! Now I get "Host 'blahblah' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server. I think I just have to give access to my user for any ipaddress next. Either way thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: My pleasure; and yup, `GRANT USER` is your friend :) Good luck!